# How to SSH into a Pi outdoors

Tags: ssh, pi-4, static-ip

Pi newbie here, please kick me in the right direction if this is a repeat question, I'm unsure of the correct terminology for what I'm trying to achieve.

Right, so I'm beginning my RPi learning, I'm undertaking a project using OpenCV. The project will require the Pi to live permanently outdoors. Before all of that, I need a 5 minute video from the Pi of the environment to get a good starting point for my project, however, when I take my laptop to the area I'd be mounting the Pi, connect to my mobile hotspot and try to SSH into the Pi, I just get this error from Bitvise:

```
Connection failed. FlowSocketConnector: Failed to connect to target address. Windows error 10060.
```

I've briefly seen things like 'Setting up a static IP' and 'Port Forwarding'. However I'm not 100% sure whether or not these will achieve what I'm after. Obvious everything I learn will benefit, but I'm also running another business so until I have a bit more time to dedicate I'd rather have a clearer path to what I need to learn to achieve my goal, albeit this is probably IoT 101 to you guys!

Again, if this has already been answered, please throw me into right direction!

Cheers guys.

Comment: when you connect to the mobile hotspot, how are you trying to access the pi? IP address? hostname?

Comment: Yeah, so IP address & port, then user & password for authentication.

Comment: "I'm not 100% sure whether or not these will achieve what I'm after" we don't know what you are after or what you have tried. Your question is vague generalities with no hard data.

Comment: Well, given I say "when I take my laptop to the area I'd be mounting the Pi, connect to my mobile hotspot and try to SSH into the Pi, I just get this error from Bitvise:" along with the error code, i thought it was clear that my error was logging into the Pi, but I will edit for clarification.

Comment: Does the Pi have a fixed IP address, or how are you determining the address to connect to?

Comment: how is the pi getting an IP address?

Comment: I think the first step would be to get it working in an environment where you can hook keyboard and monitor up to the Pi.

Answer (score 1):

Because a lot of important information is missing, we fall back to a way to detemine what is wrong.

Step 1: is your Pi OK?

- We assume that the Pi boots correctly.
- Does the Pi get an IP address? Can you try to connect a keyboard/screen for debugging purposes? Can you read the Pi's logging.

If all is well, you will see in the syslog (`/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/syslog.1`) something like:

```
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  7 12:38:42 chi dhcpcd[393]: wlan0: using static address 192.168.178.7/24
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  7 12:38:42 chi dhcpcd[393]: wlan0: adding route to 192.168.178.0/24
/var/log/syslog.1:Mar  7 12:38:42 chi dhcpcd[393]: wlan0: adding default route via 192.168.178.1
```

which will tell you that your WiFi is connected, and your Pi has an IP address.

If there is no IP address, you will need to start debugging your Pi's network access.

Is your ssh server running? Do you have a file `ssh` in `/boot`?

Can you ping the mobile hotspot from the Pi?

2: Your mobile hotspot.

Is there a way to get some logging or status information out of it (for example: via a web-page, or via the display)? Do you see there that the Pi connects? And your laptop too?

Does your hotspot use client isolation? If so: turn that off.

3: Windows.
Check your Windows setup. (out of scope for this site, and I am not really great in Windows troubleshooting)

Some other things to check:

- Ping everything, from PC to access point, from Pi to PC etcetera.
- Can your Pi see the Internet via your hotspot?
- Is it possible to try this wired?